# How to split up text columns and combine them into new column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I have a df:

```
             FROM              TO
0  LA:Los_Angeles     NY:New_York
1     NY:New_York  LA:Los_Angeles
```

I want to combine parts of the text into a new column like so:

```
             FROM              TO  MERGED
0  LA:Los_Angeles     NY:New_York  LA->NY
1     NY:New_York  LA:Los_Angeles  NY->LA
```

So far my code is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FROM':['LA:Los_Angeles', 'NY:New_York'], 'TO':['NY:New_York', 'LA:Los_Angeles']})
print(df)
df['MERGED'] = str(df['FROM']).split(':')[0] + '->' + str(df['TO']).split(':')[0]
print(df)
```

Which gives back:

```
             FROM              TO               MERGED
0  LA:Los_Angeles     NY:New_York  0    LA->0       NY
1     NY:New_York  LA:Los_Angeles  0    LA->0       NY
```

It seems to only be grabbing the first row and performing the operation. It also seems to be including the index in the string somehow, the '0' leading the city. Not too sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: `df["FROM"].str.extract("(\w{2}):")+"->"+df["TO"].str.extract("(\w{2}):")`

Comment: what you tried to do was more `df['FROM'].str.split(':', expand=True)[0]` (same for TO)

Comment: although that does work i wanted a less 'hard coded' way. your solution has '{2}' which i believe is for getting 2 chars before ':'? I wanted to just split the string on ':' and grab everything left of it aka index 0 @HenryYik

Comment: then just replace it with `\w+`.

Comment: @Ben.T werid. I was able to use my code above in a different program without specifying expand=True. Oh well thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df['MERGED'] = df['FROM'].str.split(':').str.get(0) + '->' +df['TO'].str.split(':').str.get(0)

    FROM            TO              MERGED
0   LA:Los_Angeles  NY:New_York     LA->NY
1   NY:New_York     LA:Los_Angeles  NY->LA
```