# add specific part of one column values to another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `dataframe`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'existing_indiv': ['stac.Altered', 'MASO.MHD'], 'queries': ['modify', 'change']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    existing_indiv     queries
0   stac.Altered       modify
1   MASO.MHD           change
```

I want to add the `period` and the `word` before the `period` to the beginning of the `values` of `the queries column`

**Expected outcome:**

```
    existing_indiv     queries
0   stac.Altered       stac.modify
1   MASO.MHD           MASO.change
```

Any ideas?

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711728/how-to-split-up-text-columns-and-combine-them-into-new-column-in-pandas-datafram

Comment: .apply() method with lambda row would works correctly but is relatively slow:

    df['queries'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['existing_indiv'].split('.')[0] + '.' + row['queries'], axis=1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.str.extract` and regex `^([^.]+\.)` to extract everything before the first `.`:

```
df.queries = df.existing_indiv.str.extract('^([^.]+\.)', expand=False) + df.queries

df
  existing_indiv      queries
0   stac.Altered  stac.modify
1       MASO.MHD  MASO.change
```

If you prefer `.str.split`:

```
df.existing_indiv.str.split('.').str[0] + '.' + df.queries

0    stac.modify
1    MASO.change
dtype: object
```